# Why does Perl say Global symbol "SYMBOL" requires explicit package name at PROGRAM.pl line X?

Tags: perl

I´m writing my first programs in Perl, and wrote this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
$animal = "camel";
print($animal);
```

When I run it, I get these messages from the Windows command-line:

```
Global symbol "animal" requires explicit package name at stringanimal.pl line 3
Global symbol "animal" requires explicit package name at stringanimal.pl line 4
```

Please, could anyone what these messages mean?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`use strict;` forces you to declare your variables before using them. If you don't (as in your code sample), you'll get that error.

To declare your variable, change this line:

```
$animal = "camell";
```

To:

```
my $animal = "camell";
```

See "[Declaring variables](http://theoryx5.uwinnipeg.ca/programming/node12.html)" for a more in-depth explanation, and also the Perldoc section for [`use strict`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebtut.html#use-strict).

P.S. Camel is spelt "camel" :-)

**Edit:** What the error message actually means is that Perl can't find a variable named `$animal` since it hasn't been declared, and assumes that it must be a variable defined in a package, but that you forgot to prefix it with the package name, e.g. `$packageName::animal`. Obviously, this isn't the case here, you simply hadn't declared `$animal`.

Comment: A package is Perl's way of splitting code into multiple files (so that individual related pieces of code can be "packaged" together and reused on different projects). This also helps keep you away from having a single 300000-line script -- a maintenance nightmare :-). See [this tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html).

Comment: packages are just namespaces. You can have a ton of them in the same file.

Comment: @Axeman: Yeah, good point. I should have said "chunks" and not "files". I've gotten too used to languages that enforce one namespace/package per file (which I think is generally a good idea anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You have to put:

```
my $animal = "camel"
```

when using `use strict`.