# Global symbol "$variable" requires explicit package name at filename.pl

Tags: perl

From my understand of perl, i think that error message means i have an undeclared variable called **$something** for example ? I have a **foreach** statement as such :

```
foreach my $as (@ARRAYY) {
            $db-> execute($as->[1],$as->[0],$Key);
        }
```

I get an error on **$as** saying :

```
Global symbol "$as" requires explicit package name at filename.pl
```

My confusion is, hasn't $as been already declared in the foreach statement ? as :

**my $as ?** before the foreach keyword ?

Thank you for reading. Your thoughts are highly appreciated !

**Update**

```
foreach my $as (@ASPATH) {
            #print "\tASPATH : $as->[0]","\t" ;
            #print "\tASINDEX : $as->[1] \n" ;
            $as_path->execute($as->[1],$as->[0],$UpdateKey);
        }
```

Comment: Yes, the `$as` variable is declared in that foreach loop. Check the line number that you get with that error and see which line it points to.

Comment: If you reply with feedback, I might be able to help you before I have to leave.

Comment: @TLP i will add the real code as an edit update, please refresh in 10 seconds :) It actually points to the line where i use the variable.

Comment: Yes, but I asked you to verify that the error comes from the line number in your source code that you think it does. The error can be two things: 1) `$as` is seen somewhere else, 2) you have some kind of syntax error (missing parenthesis, semi-colon, etc) above that for loop which interrupts the `my $as` declaration.

Comment: @TLP Your second assumption is correct. Will you like to reply as an answer so that i may mark you as the answer to my question ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Perl say Global symbol "SYMBOL" requires explicit package name at PROGRAM.pl line X?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257179/why-does-perl-say-global-symbol-symbol-requires-explicit-package-name-at-progr)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting comment as answer, as requested.

The error can be two things:

1. `$as` is seen somewhere else.
2. You have some kind of syntax error (missing parenthesis, semi-colon, etc) above that for loop which interrupts the `my $as` declaration.