# Printing an array variable displaying all its elements using main:: .

Tags: arrays, perl, variables

The `@main::match_to_array` prints out only the last element in the array `@match_to_array` , not the whole array.

I did my code with reference to [this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141412/global-symbol-requires-explicit-package-name).

The input HTML consists of 
`dmit@sp.com 
    ems@es.com 
    dew@es.com 
    dmit@sp.com 
    erg@es.com`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl –w

use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd;

sub extractMail {

    my $perl_path = cwd;
    # Full HTML.htm
    if(-e 'test.html') { 

    open(OPENFILE, "$perl_path/test.html") or die "Unable to open file";

    }

    my @email = <OPENFILE>;
    close OPENFILE;

    foreach my $email (@email){

        if ($email =~ /regex to match data/{
        my $match = "$1\n";

        our @match_to_array = split ("\n",$match);

        } # end of if statement 

    } # end of foreach
} # end of subroutine extractMail


    for (my $a = 1;$a<=1;$a++){

    &extractMail;

    print @main::match_to_array;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have misunderstood the post. The point is to declare the variable at the right place. In this case, you should probably `return` the value from the subroutine. Moreover, by assigning to an array

```
@match_to_array = split /\n/, $match;
```

you are overwriting the previous contents of the array. Use `push` instead.

Untested:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl –w

use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd;

sub extractMail {
    my $perl_path = cwd;
    if (-e 'test.html') { 
        open my $OPENFILE, "$perl_path/test.html" or die "Unable to open file: $!";
    }

    my @match_to_array;
    while (my $email = <$OPENFILE>) {
        if ($email =~ /regex to match data/) {
            my $match = "$1\n";
            push @match_to_array, split /\n/, $match;
        }
    }
    return @match_to_array;
}


for my $i (1 .. 1) {
    my @match_to_array = extractMail();
    print "@match_to_array\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There's an error of  "Global symbol "$OPENFILE" requires explicit package name " . I tried changing to `our $OPENFILE` and using `$main::OPENFILE` subsequently, it didn't work.

Comment: You should never have to use `our` except for `@ISA` or when requested by modules (e.g. `our @EXPORT_OK`), and there's never a reason to use or `$main::` at all. Stop using them. Forget about them. You're heading in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
my @email = <OPENFILE>;
close OPENFILE;
```

This might be the Problem, after those lines @email is containg one element, namely "dmit@sp.com ems@es.com ...".

Afterwards you're doing this:

```
foreach my $email (@email)
```

This will loop once, with

```
$email = "dmit@sp.com ems@es.com ..."
```

Then your regex removes everything BUT "dmit@sp.com" and leads you to the conclusion that only one element of your list is processed.

Try reading up on [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) to generate an array out of your space-separated list