# Perl Error: Global symbol requires explicit package name

Tags: perl, compiler-errors

I have a file that has

```
#File content
   word1 -> word2
word3 -> word4
```

and I need to put this in 2 different arrays as

```
@array1 = word1, word3
@array2 = word2, word4
```

My code is as below

```
my @mappings = `cat $file_name`; 
foreach my $map (@mappings) { 
    $map =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g; #Remove leading and trailing spaces 
    next if ($map =~ /^#/); 
    my @Mainarray = split ('->',$map); 
    my @array1 = push(@array1,@Mainarray[0]); **#Error line**
    my @array2 = push(@array2,@Mainarray[1]); **#Error line**
    print("Array1: @array1\nArray2:@array2\n"); 
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
Global symbol "@array1" requires explicit package name.
Global symbol "@array2" requires explicit package name.
```

Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Global symbol requires explicit package name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141412/global-symbol-requires-explicit-package-name)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  Please provide complete code; you are almost certainly using `use strict;` and `use warnings;` which you don't show.  You also don't show the line numbers which Perl generates with the error message. Please read up on how to make an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: I have use strict in my code. Entire code is almost 500-600 lines. So I wont be able to paste it. I just updated the error lines in the code above by writing a small comment next to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the way you have it is redefining `@array1` & `@array2` each time through the foreach loop, and trying to set them equal to a value that contains an undefined value (itself).  Try this:

```
my @mappings = `cat $file_name`;
my @array1;
my @array2;
foreach my $map (@mappings) { 
  $map =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g; #Remove leading and trailing spaces 
  next if ($map =~ /^#/); 
  my @Mainarray = split (/->/,$map); 
  push(@array1, $Mainarray[0]); 
  push(@array2, $Mainarray[1]);
  print("Array1: @array1\nArray2:@array2\n"); 
}
```

Comment: That works perfect! Never realized the redefining part when it loops! Thank you.

Comment: yes when you have `my` in a loop, the variable gets reset each time.

Comment: Use `$Mainarray[0]` to extract a single element from an array. Also `use warnings`