# File open error - Global symbol "$infilename" requires explicit package name

Tags: perl

I'm writing my first perl script and can't get it to compile.  I want to read in a file and output each line that matches a regex criteria to a new file.  I'm getting a "global symbol requires explicit package name" error, which seems to be related to issues with variable scope from what I've read.  I can't figure out what's wrong with my code though.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Stripping lines from data dump where WREN column is FFF\n" 

my $infilename = "./test_in.txt";
my $outfilename = "./test_out.txt";
my $in = undef;

open($in,  "<",  $infilename)  or die "Can't open $infilename: $!";
open(my $out, ">",  $outfilename) or die "Can't open $outfilename: $!";

while (<$in>) {     # assigns each line in turn to $_
   if (/.{73}FFF/){
      print $out $_;
   }
}
```

Error message:

```
syntax error at strip_nonwrites.pl line 8, near "my "
Global symbol "$infilename" requires explicit package name at strip_nonwrites.pl line 8.
Global symbol "$infilename" requires explicit package name at strip_nonwrites.pl line 12.
Global symbol "$infilename" requires explicit package name at strip_nonwrites.pl line 12.
Execution of strip_nonwrites.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Comment: Add a semicolon `;` in print statement in line 5. And when you are using `use warnings`, no need to add `-w` in `shebang` line, both have same meaning.

Comment: @serenesat, `-w` will also affect modules (assuming they don't already have `use warnings`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Global symbol requires explicit package name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141412/global-symbol-requires-explicit-package-name)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not uncommon that a single syntax error will throw off the parser enough to spawn multiple false errors after the fact.  This is such a case.

Your 1st error is the one to pay attention to.  You are missing a semicolon at the end of line 6 (`near "my "` on `line 8`).

All of the "Global symbol ..." errors that follow are just confusion created by trying to parse lines 6..8 as a single command.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't terminating your `print` statement with a semicolon `;` so the `my $infilename` is being treated as part of that statement.

Answer (score 3):

As you have read, you have a missing semicolon at the end of the first `print` statement. Later error messages will depend on what Perl has decded to make of your erroneous script, and are often unreliable.

Some other points

- You should `use warnings` in preference to `-w` on the command line or shebang line. Both at once is wrong
- There is no need for a leading `./` on data files. That only applies when running an executable from the shell, when PATH is searched for the given file name if no path is provided
- You should declare your lexical variables as late as possible in your program. In the case of file handles, that is inside the `open` call, as you did with `$out`
- A `select` statement allows you to write subsequent `print` calls without having to specify a file handle
- It is probably better to use `substr` or `unpack` to extract fixed-position substrings from each record

That leaves a program that looks like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Stripping lines from data dump where WREN column is FFF\n";

my ($infilename, $outfilename) = qw/ test_in.txt test_out.txt /;

open my $in_fh,  '<',  $infilename   or die qq{Can't open "$infilename" for input: $!};
open my $out_fh, '<',  $outfilename  or die qq{Can't open "$outfilename" for output: $!};
select $out_fh;

while ( <$in_fh> ) {
   print if substr($_, 73, 3) eq 'FFF';
}
```