# Global symbol "$global_var1" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $global_var1"?) at module1.pm

Tags: perl, strict

I have two module files, in `module2` I have a global variable,

```
$global_var1 = 'global_var_sub';
sub global_var_sub
{
    return something;
}
```

now, in `module1`, I do `use module2;` and then try to print variables from `module2`.
This was working correctly and outputs were shown as expected. (I am using this global variable in many subroutines inside `module1`)

After this I added `use strict;` and `use warnings;` to `module1`, and the following error is shown when I compile `module1`:

> Global symbol "$global_var1" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $global_var1"?) at module1.pm

How do i solve this?

Comment: When you use `strict` pragma you need to declare package variables with [`our`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our) as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3141544/2173773) answer

Comment: @HåkonHægland so should I  declare the variable in both the module files?

Comment: No you declare it only in `module2.pm` here is an example: https://pastebin.com/JXqLiQtq